# Поддержка jQuery в Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: jquery, dreamweaver

В dreamweaver cs5 заявлена  поддержка jQuery. Ну и где она? Никаких подсказок!
Для css3 ставил плагин, может и для jQuery надо?

Comment: Скорее надо писать в Спортлото^Wsupport@adobe.com

Answer (score 1):

Есть поддержка и подсказки присутствуют. Именно из-за этого, я его для этих нужд и использую. Достаточно удобно. Может версия DW у вас старовата?

P.S. Мелькнула мыслишка... Подсказки начинают работать только после того, как вы в документ библиотеку подключили. Возможно это вы упустили?